# How many elements of order 7 in a Non-simple group of order 168?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If the group is simple, sylow is enough, otherwise i have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you still use Sylow theory, except that there are two cases.

Let $G$ be a group of order 168. The number $n_7$ of Sylow 7-subgroups of $G$ must equal $1$ or $8$. If $n _7 = 1$, then there's a unique element of order 7. If $n_7 = 8$, there there are $8 \cdot 6 = 48$ elements of order 7.

Comment: Is there no way to tell which is it? Thanks anyway

Comment: Not unless you know more about the group. There could be non-simple groups of order 168 with $n_7 = 1$ and others with $n_7 = 8$.

Comment: @manthanomen can you please explain why $8$  is possible and furthermore why multiply by $6$?